# Сохранение размера шрифта tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Тестовый редактор tinyMCE перестал сохранять размер шрифта. Может кто сталкивался с таким? Версия 2.1.

Comment: Что значит "сохранять"? При вставке? Вставка при копировании из чего? Нет ли у вас собственного стиля, подключенного в options? Может у вас в опциях стоит paste_as_text: true вставлять как текст? Распишите подробней действия и приведите настройки редактора

Comment: Когда пишешь текст или его редактируешь - хочешь изменить ему размер шрифта. Так вот при сохранении текста - изменение размера шрифта не сохраняется в отличие от "жирного и наклонного стиля". Хочу отметить, что раньше такого "косяка" не было. Ошибки в  консоли - нет. Есть предположение нужно перезалить скрипты редактора, но мне нужно именно эта версия.

Comment: Посмотрите html, который сохраняется. Может с размером в редакторе все нормально, но перебивается стилями уже там, где этот текст выводится?

Comment: Нет, он в контроллер уже без размера приходит

Comment: Решение найдено в файле tinymce_init.blade.php найти строку extended_valid_elements :  и прописать (добавить) span [itemprop|itemscope|itemtype|class]

Comment: скорей всего этот пункт и в options можно прописать, не изменяя исходники